# Bootstrap Multiselect inside default_popup chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know if the [Boostrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin works in `default_popup` for chrome extensions with Manifest V3?

I saved jQuery, Bootstrap & [Boostrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) into the chrome extension and loaded them within popup.js as per [guide on the plugins page](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).

Popup.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

since I can't initialise the plugin within popup.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });
</script>
```

as I get the error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-4lndvGzcMkUnvdfuDCzL0sOEfIW9cdivCN8IPHGBevM='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
>
> popup.html:121 Refused to execute inline script because it violates
> the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-4lndvGzcMkUnvdfuDCzL0sOEfIW9cdivCN8IPHGBevM='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

thus I placed it into popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    });
console.log("multiselect");
});
```

I'm not getting any error message in the console within extension popup  (only the log message) but bootstrap multiselect is not showing, only a button "None selected".

Answer (score 1):

For Manifest V2

Verify that you have added the 'unsafe-inline' to your content security policy manifest.json file.

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'",
```

Comment: I think unsafe-inline is not supported in manifest v3 (?)

Comment: You did not mention that in your first post.

Comment: yes sorry, I guess one is working always with a current version unless otherwise stated. (Somebody else though downvoted your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm using Bootstrap v5 which isn't supported https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1226, [max v4](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1226#issuecomment-1044053630).

The guide doesn't mention this, only max jQuery v 2.x is pointed out.

Also then console complained about missing popper.js but after adding this it worked.